# reading a txt file: Permission denied - postgis

Tags: postgresql, import, postgis, permission-denied

I get this error while trying to copy some data from a txt file to a table in a database, in postgis/postgres... (I am using windows 10).

```
ERROR:  could not open file "C:\Users\Luchito\Desktop\output_1.txt" for reading: Permission denied
```

The file has all permission "on"... Any help?

Comment: Are you sure the file is accessible by a different user than you? Have you tried moving it to some shared directory?

Comment: Please show us the complete statement that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql does not run with administrator privileges dans does not have access to your own user space most likely.
If you do a right click on the file, click `Properties` then `Security`, then `Users` (or `Authenticated Users` I am not sure) and check `Full Control`. It should allow Postgres to read the file